# Eliminating duplicate values in a nothasable list

Tags: python

I want to eliminate duplicate values in my list(`alist`). Here, I have done this, but i am getting this error: `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`
So, how can I eliminate the duplicate values in such a list that is unhashable as below.
**Notice that third values in the list(`alist[2]`) are useless, you can ignore them.**

```
  alist=[
               [('as','bn',1),('ck','dy',1),('et','fv',2)],
               [('as','bn',1),('gx','ha',3)],
               [('ck','dy',1),('kj','mw',5)]
        ]

            b=[]

            for i in alist:
                a =[]
                for j in i:
                    if (j[0],j[1]) not in a:
                        a.append((j[0],j[1]))
                c = list(set(b)-set(a))
                b.append(c)
```

Expected outcome:

```
  alist=[
               [('as','bn',1),('ck','dy',1),('et','fv',2)],
               [('gx','ha',3)],
               [('kj','mw',5)]
        ]
```

Comment: You have a list of tuples and wish to remove any tuples present in any preceding lists?

Comment: Your expected output is not valid Python.  Your input list is a list of lists.  Is your expected outcome a list of lists as well, or just a list of the unique tuples that appeared anywhere in your list of lists?  Also, does order matter to you?

Comment: the expected outcome is also a list of list. Yes, the order matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want something like the following:

```
alist  =[[('as','bn',1),('ck','dy',1),('et','fv',2)],
         [('as','bn',1),('gx','ha',3)],
         [('ck','dy',1),('kj','mw',5)]]

seen = set()
b = []
for i in alist:
    a = []
    for j in i:
        if (j[0], j[1]) not in seen:
            a.append(j)
            seen.add((j[0], j[1]))
    b.append(a)

alist = b
```

Result:

```
>>> pprint.pprint(alist)
[[('as', 'bn', 1), ('ck', 'dy', 1), ('et', 'fv', 2)],
 [('gx', 'ha', 3)],
 [('kj', 'mw', 5)]]
```

Note that based on your code I went with the assumption that you want to remove any tuples where the first two elements match a tuple that was seen earlier.  If you want to use the entire tuple for comparison instead of just the first two values from the tuple, change the code to use `if j not in seen:` and `seen.add(j)`.